# Tarefa no Moodle

Tags: moodle

Gostaria de saber se é possível restringir que o aluno edite/apague o arquivo postado(upado) de uma Tarefa, que mesmo dentro do prazo, já tenha sido dado a respectiva nota pelo professor/avaliador?

Comment: coloque na opção Configurações de envio>Máximo de tentativas o valor igual a 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque na opção Configurações de envio>Máximo de tentativas o valor igual a 1